# Running diagnostics on a driver bug?

Tags: release-freya, hardware, wifi

I own an [HP ProBook 450 G2](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=6943827&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=4059) with Freya installed over it.

My WiFi driver keeps crashing and I have to enable it through a tip I found in a forum [post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1543006&page=160&p=13215305#post13215305), by executing.

```
sudo rmmod rtl8723be && sudo modprobe rtl8723be
```

How do I run diagnostics on it before reporting it as a bug?